# Disable all keys but copy paste combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a code for number field where i have disabled all keys except number keys

```js
function doValidation(event) {
  var charCode = event.keyCode;
  if (charCode != 190 && charCode != 40 && charCode != 39 && charCode != 38 && charCode != 37 && charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode < 96 || charCode > 105))
    return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="doValidation(event)">
```

Now i want to enable ctrl+c and ctrl+v in this funtion.

Comment: never, never, NEVER disable ctr+c ,ctr+v, ctr+.. or right click, for the number, use input type number

Comment: it is not for me to decide i was told to do so, can you help me out ? :(

Comment: you may consider [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: may not help as i have some more customization for it, but thanks

Comment: As madalinivascu mentioned instead of temporary fixes like this, for all this key press you can use <input type="number">. You can also set min/max value for this input. Copy/paste will be allowed by default.

Comment: the person im working for want this weird thing i would've just used input type number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this like below :)

```
var is_ctrl_pressed = false;
$('#number_input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var code = e.which;
    if ((code > 47 && code < 59) || (code > 95 && code < 106) || (is_ctrl_pressed && (code == 67 || code == 86))) {
        return true;
    } else if (code == 17) {
        is_ctrl_pressed = true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
$('#number_input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 17) {
        is_ctrl_pressed = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i got the logic, i will try to make it work. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will be helpful.

```
$('input[type="number"]').keypress(function(e){
  //Numbers 47 to 57 are the key code of digit 0 to 9.
  if (![48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57].includes(e.keyCode)){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: i already have enabled 0-9 numbers i need to enable ctrl+c and ctrl+v

Comment: @AftabIshfaq Why you need to enable them, they are already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Disable Right click
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());

// Disable key down
document.onkeydown = disableSelectCopy;

// Disable mouse down
document.onmousedown = dMDown;

// Disable click
document.onclick = dOClick;

function dMDown(e) { return false; }

function dOClick() { return true; }

function disableSelectCopy(e) {
    // current pressed key
    var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    if ((e.ctrlKey && (pressedKey == "c" || pressedKey == "x" || pressedKey == "v" || pressedKey == "a" || pressedKey == "u")) ||  e.keyCode == 123) {
        return false;
    }
}
```